# Python: Why is it saying my method isn't defined when it clearly is?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class GameMech:
    def __init__(self ,aCharacter):
        print("A battle is starting")
    def getMP(self, aCharacter):
        return aCharacter.mp
    def getHP(aCharacter):
        return aCharacter.hp
    def getAtk(aCharacter):
        return aCharacter.atk
    def getDef(aCharacter):
        return aCharacter.defense
    def usePotion(aCharacter):
        aCharacter.hp += 100
        return aCharacter.hp
    def useSpecial(self, aCharacter, target):
        if aCharacter.mp >= 100:
            target.hp -= 45

    def dead(self, aCharacter):
        return aCharacter.name +" is now dead"
    def attack(self, aCharacter, target):
        if target.hp - (aCharacter.atk/aCharacter.defense) <= 0:
            dead(target)
        else:
            target.hp - aCharacter.atk/aCharacter.defense
            print(getHP(target))
    def guard(self, aCharacter):
        print(aCharacter + "was unharmed")
        if aCharacter.hp <= 50:
            retaliation(aCharacter, target)
    def retaliation(self ,aCharacter, target):
        target.hp - (aCharacter.atk/10)
        print(getHP(target))

    def battleMenu(aNumber, self):
        if aNumber == 1:
            attack(aCharacter, target)
        if aNumber == 2:
            guard(aCharacter)
            print(aCharacter + " was unharmed!")
        if aNumber == 3:
            useSpecial(aCharacter, target)
            print(getHP(target))
        if aNumber == 4:
            heal = useItem(aCharacter)
            print(heal)

    def myTurn(self):
        print("ATTACK")
        print("GUARD")
        print("SPECIAL")
        print("ITEM")
        aNumber = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
        battleMenu(aNumber)

    def oppTurn(self):
        print("It is the opponent's turn")
        randomNum = random.randint(1,4)
        battleMenu(randomNum)
```

a few notes, obviously due to this formatting you can't tell that all my methods are actually under the class, but they are.
you can ignore the first few parts, the part im focusing on is battle menu. 
So i'm creating a little text game as a project for myself, pure leisure nothing academic or for a job. Just a little game for myself to help me jog my memory in regards to python. So that's where the gut of my game is, the character class is an another file and there's nothing important in there just the attributes of character (hp, mp, atk, def)
here's the main

```
import random
import character
import battle



#create a battle menu
#and a character value check menu
#add buttons




def main():
char1 = character.Character("Charlie", 5000, 2000, 1500, 750)
char2 = character.Character("Mark", 2000, 4000, 2000, 900)

newGame = battle.GameMech(char1)
while char1.hp != 0 or char2.hp != 0:
    newGame.myTurn()
    newGame.oppTurn()
```

main()
(not sure why it's not including the definition of my main in the code snippet)
Any how I'm getting this error saying "name 'battleMenu' is not defined".
Name usually applies to variables correct? But battleMenu is a method is there a reason i'm getting this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\PythonGame\mainGame.py", line 22, in <module>
  main()
File "E:\PythonGame\mainGame.py", line 20, in main
  newGame.myTurn()
File "E:\PythonGame\battle.py", line 55, in myTurn
  battleMenu(self,aNumber)
NameError: name 'battleMenu' is not defined
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

To call a method, you need to mention the instance you're calling it on, so you need to do `self.battleMenu()`.  You need to make similar changes for all of the method calls in your code.  You also need to add a `self` argument to all your methods so that these changes will work.  You also need to read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial) to get an understanding of Python basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.battleMenu(...)  # note the "self" here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it wrongly, `def battleMenu(aNumber):` , your function is not defined as an instance function, neither as a static method, If you want a static function you should first annotate the method as a static one , by using `@staticmethod` annotation.

Then call your function as - `GameMech.battleMenu(random)` .

If you want it to be an instance function, change the definition to `def battleMenu(self, aNumber):` and then check.

Comment: I did that, but now it's referring to line 55 saying battleMenu(aNumber) is not defined, line55 is under myTurn(), so now I'm even more confused. I actually remembered after i posted this that for it to be an instance a self is needed, and static is when it's out side of the class so it doesn't need the self.

Comment: What did you do? first or second? I think second would be better

Comment: I believe i had at first, battleMenu(self, aNumber) does it make a huge difference?